# How to change behavior of ctrl+t in Firefox to open new tabs next to current tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I tested `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` in `about:config` but this works only for opening new tabs using mouse middle button.

Comment: Set `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent` to `true`; see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1372579/598527).

Answer (score 26):

As of Firefox 61 this behavior is available natively:

1. Navigate to `about:config`
2. Find the `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent` row
3. Toggle it to `true` by double-clicking the row

Comment: The other answers are outdated, it's unfortunate that this one hasn't yet received any attention (aside from my vote).

Comment: @user598527 : your comment at the question will solve this issue in a few years

Answer (score 5):

You could try Tab Mix Plus, an add-on I've been using since forever-ish.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/

Once installed, in the Tab Mix Plus options, Events -> New Tabs -> "Open new tabs next to current one". The option below it, "Open other tabs next to current one", doesn't do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: In fact, I had to uncheck "Only if related to current tab" under checked "Open other tabs next to current one".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a relevant bug report:

> [Bug 528005 - Provide ways of opening new tabs next to the current tab](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=528005)

Here are some more suggested extensions:

- [Always Right](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/always-right/)
- [Open Tabs Next to Current](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/open-tabs-next-to-current/)
- [Open Tabs Next to Current Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/open-tabs-next-to-current-plus/)

Personally I'm using the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Tab Control addon for the similar reason.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-control/

There is a setting: Position new tabs to right of current tab.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer mentioned, this can be enabled by the `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent` option in `about:config`.

If one wants to sync this setting across devices, one needs to turn on `services.sync.prefs.dangerously_allow_arbitrary`. This syncs all custom settings in `about:config`. It looks like `insertAfterCurrent` does not have a separate `services.sync` setting for it, so sync needs to be turned on for all settings.